# Encode long into an int and vice versa

Tags: java, type-conversion, integer, long-integer

If I have an application, Ryno, that produces unique increasing long numbers. I have another application, Cyan,that sends a message and needs a unique integer id. I would want to use the number from Ryno as the id for message in Cyan. Is there a way to encode long to int.  Cyan will not send no more than 1 billion messages

Comment: Not sure what will happen in lonValue > Integer.MAX_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine

```
    long f = 10292029202924l;
    System.out.println(f);
    int v = (int)f;
    System.out.println(v);
    System.out.println((f & xFFFFFFFF);
```

prints

> 10292029202924
>   1287561708
>   1287561708

```
    f = -1L;
    v = (int)f;
    System.out.println(v);
    v = (int)(f & 0x7FFFFFFF); // mask off sign extension
    System.out.println(v);
```

prints

> -1 
>   2147483647